# addClass using Angularjs on particular ul li

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to addclass to particular li on select element

```
$("#products").autocomplete({ /*products id of search box for apply autosearching */
        source: $scope.availableProducts,/*product data fateched*/
        select: function(event, ui ) { /*as product is selected direcly add to page of active tab and page */
                  var id = angular.element('.ng-isolate-scope .active').attr('id'); /* To get active tab id and page id*/
                  var this_page_id=angular.element('#get_id_'+id+'').find('li.active').attr('data-id');
                 if (isNaN(this_page_id))
                         {
                                   this_page_id=page.pageID;
                 angular.element('#get_id_'+id+' ').find('li').eq(0).addClass('active');
                         }/*if page is not selected then by default insert in first page*/                  

                  });/*end of angular.forEach*/
            }/*end select */
}); /* end of $("#products").autocomplete */
```

> angular.element('#get_id_'+id+'
>   ').find('li').eq(0).addclass('active');

not working giving error as

> TypeError: angular.element(...).find(...).eq(...).addClass is not a
>   function
>
> angular.element('#get_id_'+id+'
>   ').find('li').eq(0).addClass('active');

Comment: If you have jQuery then why you are using `angular.element()`? just make jquery selector and do it. As i can see you have `autocomplete` and you have a `$` for jQuery.

Comment: also this need to be understand from docs `find() - **Limited to lookups by tag name**`

Answer (score 2):

It should be much easier to drop all of the JQuery code and use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

Comment: thank you for reply sir but will you please elaborate it

Comment: Can you post the code that actually renders the list? You'd use ng-class within this code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is because of typo , use `addClass` (c caps) instead of `addclass`

https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

This should work only if you are reffering Jquery :-

```
  angular.element('#get_id_'+id).find('li').eq(0).addClass('active');
```

Comment: Are you referring Jquery?, because Angular JQLite not support all selectors?

Comment: i am trying to worked it in angular but getting failure, this can be done by jQuery easily

Comment: In that case there is no selector like this in angular Sachin.. angular.Element can't select element using this selector

Comment: Also this is not the angular way, you should check ng-class